# Python Alphanumeric Regex

Tags: python, regex, match

Below I have the following regex:

```
alphanumeric = compile('^[\w\d ]+$')
```

I'm running the current data against this regex:

```
Tomkiewicz Zigomalas Andrade Mcwalters
```

I have a separate regex to identify alpha characters only, yet the data above still matches the alphanumeric criteria.

Edit: How do I stop the only alpha data matching with the regex above?

Comment: A character class in brackets matches _any_ of the expressions.  `[\w\d]` means "either a number, or a letter."  If you only want letters, remove the `\d`.

Comment: I want letters and numbers. I want it to only match against alphanumeric data, yet it matches against the data which is only alpha characters.

Comment: @g.d.d.c `\w` includes numbers as well :-)

Comment: So "alphanumeric data" must contain at least one digit and at least one letter? ex. "1a" is alphanumeric, but "1" isn't and "a" isn't?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Description: It can be in two forms:

1. Starts with numeric chars  then there should be some chars, followed by any number of alpha-numeric chars are possible.
2. Starts with alphabets, then some numbers, followed by any number of alpha-numeric chars are possible.

Demo:

```
>>> an_re = r"(\d+[A-Z])|([A-Z]+\d)[\dA-Z]*"
>>> re.search(an_re, '12345', re.I) # not acceptable string
>>> re.search(an_re, 'abcd', re.I) # not acceptable string 
>>> re.search(an_re, 'abc1', re.I) # acceptable string 
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x14153e8>
>>> re.search(an_re, '1abc', re.I)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x14153e8>
```

Comment: @Glitchezz It will work, with `I`, But understood my RE? And remember I didn't use `\w` as it includes `_` And I left `^` and `$` for you as an exercise

Answer (score 1):

Use a *lookahead* to assert the condition that at least one alpha and at least one digit are present:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])^[\w\d ]+$
```

The above RegEx utilizes two lookaheads to first check the entire string for each condition. The lookaheads search up until a single character in the specified range is found. If the assertion matches then it moves on to the next one. The last part I borrowed from the OP's original attempt and just ensures that the entire string is composed of one or more lower/upper alphas, underscores, digits, or spaces.

Comment: Tenub I tried to understand your RE but couldn't, can you explain a bit for me? (though I have bookmarked this for tomorrow lesson) +1 for advance RE example. Thanks.